# how to pause multiple symbols with mouse click in flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have been using actionscript 3 to control my animations,

I can play and reset the video but not able to pause globally.

There are totally 3 symbols,

1st Parent movieclip
2nd child moviclip with animation--> I am able to pause this.
3rd child movieclip with animation--> I am unable to pause this

Script

package lib {

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;


public class Controlstry extends MovieClip {


    public function Controlstry() {
        // constructor code
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);            
    }
    private function init(evt=null)
    {           
        if(video_mc != null)
        {
            playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, playVideo);
            pauseBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pauseVideo);
            replayBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,replayVideo);
        }
    }

    private function playVideo(evt:MouseEvent)
    {
        if(video_mc.currentFrame == video_mc.totalFrames)
        {
            video_mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
        }
        else
        {
            video_mc.play();
        }
    }

    private function pauseVideo(evt:MouseEvent)
    {
        video_mc.stop();
    }

    private function replayVideo(evt:MouseEvent)
    {
        video_mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear from your code as to what are the three movie clips which you want to control.

Assuming you have 3 movie clips nested into each other, you can call stop() on each one of them to stop their animation (assuming they have a timeline animation)

So if your structure looks like this : a-->b-->c, where a is the parent, b a child of a, and c a child of b, you can call

```
a.stop(); 
a.b.stop(); 
a.b.c.stop();
```

This is obviously assuming the fact that you have instance names declared for the child properties in the IDE.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

As per your sent FLA, you should do the following steps to achieve what you want:

1. Go inside video_mc on your stage, and select Layer 9, and give it an instance name of 'backgroundMC'.

Modify your script like this:

```
package lib {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;


    public class Controlstry extends MovieClip {


        public function Controlstry() {
            // constructor code
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);            
        }
        private function init(evt:Event=null)
        {           
            if(video_mc != null)
            {
                playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVideo);
                pauseBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseVideo);
                replayBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,replayVideo);
            }
        }

        private function playVideo(evt:MouseEvent)
        {
            if(video_mc.currentFrame == video_mc.totalFrames)
            {
                video_mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
                video_mc.backgroundMC.gotoAndPlay(1);
            }
            else
            {
                video_mc.play();
                video_mc.backgroundMC.gotoAndPlay(1);
            }
        }

        private function pauseVideo(evt:MouseEvent)
        {
            video_mc.stop();
            video_mc.backgroundMC.gotoAndStop(1);
        }

        private function replayVideo(evt:MouseEvent)
        {
            video_mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
            video_mc.backgroundMC.gotoAndPlay(1);

        }
    }   
}
```

A couple of things to note here:

1. Use MouseEvent.CLICK if you want it to respond to click events. You had used MouseEvent.DOWN
2. Always give events a type like evt:Event and not just evt=null.
3. if(video_mc != null) can be easily checked by if(video_mc).

Hope this answers the question.

Comment: No i haven't given an instance name for the the movieclip inside.

Comment: Try giving them instance names. It makes life much more easier in terms of accessing them.

Comment: Also, elaborate your problem more clearly in your question. Currently your script seems completely disconnected with your question. Please explain in more detail.

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/video_10, 

I have uploaded the flash file for reference,

http://www.filedropper.com/controlstry

Also the as3 script file.

Comment: Ok, to explain elaborately,

I want to create an interactive flash file, where there 3 buttons,

Play, Pause and Reset

Comment: Got your files, now tell me what are you trying to achieve and where is the problem?

Comment: I planned to Play my flash content only when we click on the play button. Once we click Pause button the flash content should pause everything and the third button is Reset button, when we click the reset button, the flash content will play from the beginning. So this is the Idea of my content. A very simple one

Here I have been able to control my play and reset button, but not the pause button as i have planned some animation still play even when i click the pause button.

Comment: first play the swf file and then pause it after 50 odd frames, you will c there is an animation still playing on.

Comment: See my edits above, should solve your problem, or at least give you a head start in the right direction. Please accept as as valid answer if it does meet your needs.

Comment: Cool, please select the answer as the right answer (check mark below the up and down voting buttons). Glad I could help :)

Comment: Hi, please accept the answer and close the question.